# Как получить значение из другой формы?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть `Edit1` на `Form2`, и есть `Label1` на `Form1`. Как сделать, что бы в `Label1` оказалось значение из `Edit1`?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetName := TGetName.Create(Self);
  GetName.ShowModal;

  // что написать вот здесь?
end;
```

Comment: Label не может быть равно Edit - это разные классы. Один - графический компонент, предназначенный только для отображения. Второй - для ввода. Уточните в вопросе, что именно вы хотите.

Comment: @kami, что бы текст введенный в edit отобразился на другой форме в label

Comment: Уточняем дальше. Form2 показывается модально? Т.е. пользователь (например) нажал кнопку, показалась Form2, он что-то ввел и закрыл ее. И пока он не закрыл Form2 - он не может работать с Form1. Или же обе формы видны постоянно и работать с ними можно независимо друг от друга? От этого зависит, каким способом стоит переносить текст.

Comment: @kami Form2 показывается отдельно (окно "введите имя") и после открывается Form1, где и нужно отобразить его имя. Кусочек кода добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
  nameFromUser: string;
begin
  GetName := TGetName.Create(Self);
  try
    GetName.ShowModal;
    nameFromUser := GetName.Edit1.Text;
    self.Label1.Caption := nameFromUser;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(GetName);
  end;
end;
```